# Nook Simple Touch - хак кнопки 'n', как сделать?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Возникла необходимость написать приложение для Nook Simple Touch, а с ней и необходимость отловить нажатие клавиши `'n'`. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой у нее код или как можно отловить?

```
dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
```

не помогает как и поиск в Google.

Comment: она должна работать как кнопка home

Comment: однако не получается все равно поймать ее код, он перехватывается видимо input-устройством и надо как то обработать это, вот как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка **Home** не ловится по принципиальным соображениям. Это сделано специально, чтобы у юзера всегда была возможность выйти из любой проги. Единственный способ обойти это ограничение - это кастомная прошивка.

А оно надо?

Comment: если бы не было надо, я бы не стал заморачиваться. я заливаю свое приложение на устройство пропатчив его. как то надо отловить нажатие этой кнопки, я уже и код менял у нее, делал ее и кнопкой HOME и MENU, но событие все равно проскакивает мимо обработчика. Уже не знаю что и делать.

Comment: @Макс - вы читаете что написано или нет?! Перехват нажатия на кнопку Home или ее аналога запрещен на уровне оси. Обработчик не будет работать!!!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на эти [ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android).
Да, просто так кнопку с своего приложения не перехватить. Но можно подписаться на получения нажатий ее (система будет присылать intent).